# complexity of a variant of the subset sum problem

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, subset-sum

We have a set of positive integers $N=\{a_1,...,a_n\}$, we want to select a subset $N'$ of $N$ with maximum total sum of integers such that this sum should not exceed a given integer $B$.

What is the complexity of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is NP-hard. Given an instance of your problem, the sum of the integers in the optimal subset $N'$ is at least $B$ (which implies that it must actually be exactly $B$) if and only if the corresponding subset sum instance has answer "yes".

Comment: but to prove the reverse, if we suppose that I have a solution to my problem, it means I have a subset $N'$ of N of sum <=$B$ (not necessarily $B$), how can I found a solution to the subset sum problem?

Comment: If $N'$ is an *optimal* solution to your problem and  the elements of $N'$ sum to $B$, then $N'$ is also solution to the subset sum problem. If the elements sum to less than $B$, then the subset sum problem admits no solution.

Comment: then the implication "my problem has a solution imply the subset sum problem has a solution" is not true

Comment: Indeed that implication is false. Notice however that at no point I claimed such a thing. I said that if your problem has a solution with measure at least $B$, then subset sum has a solution, and vice-versa. I.e., if you are able to solve your problem (meaning that you can find an optimal solution) then you can also solve subset sum:  you can decide whether there is a subset of numbers that sums to $B$ and, if that is the case, you can also exhibit one such subset.

Also notice that, as long as $B\ge0$, your problem *always* has a solution (since $N'=\emptyset$ is a feasible solution).

Comment: I understand now what do you mean, but what makes me confused is the fact that when we try to prove the complexity of a maximization problem, we consider its decision problem in which we have the value of the objective  function >= a given value. But in this case we have the value of the objective function <=B, how can we define the decision problem associated

Comment: and why the problem has always a solution since $B>=0$?

Comment: Yours is an optimization problem whose instance is a pair $(N,B)$ and whose objective is to maximize a certain measure. Therefore its associated decision problem has instances of the form $(N,B,k)$, where $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and it asks to decide whether there is a solution to your optimization problem with measure $\ge k$. By the constraints of your problem you know that if the answer to the decision problem is "yes" then there must be a solution with measure in $[k,B]$. 
For $B\ge 0$ the problem always admits the feasible solution $N'=\emptyset\subseteq N$, for which $\sum_{x\in N'}x=0\le B$.

Comment: can we suppose than that $k=B$?

Comment: In order to show a reduction from (the decision version of) subset sum to (the decision version of) your problem I need to show a polynomial-time transformation $f(\cdot)$ from an instance $I$ of subset sum to an instance $f(I)$ of your problem. I am therefore allowed to pick any value of $k$ for the instance $f(I)$, as long as it can be computed in polynomial time. Of course $I$ and $f(I)$ must be related: the answer to the subset sum instance $I$ must be "yes"  iff the answer on instance $f(I)$  of your problem is "yes". This is exactly what is happening by simply choosing $k=B$.

Comment: In other words, the decision version of your problem captures (the decision version of) subset sum as a special case. Therefore you can immediately conclude that the decision version of your problem is  NP-complete (a certificate is trivially the set $N'$) and hence that the optimization version is NP-hard.